# Почему BufferedWriter печатает не всю строку в файл?

Tags: java, io

Вот такой код. При выполнении печатает все, кроме нескольких строчек (примерно 20 строк из 10000).

```
public void saveAsTxt(String path) {
    try {
        processNodesToTxt();
        File file = new File(path + "/" + AuthorFirstName + " " + AuthorSecondName + " " + Title + ".txt");
        file.createNewFile();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        writer.write(TxtText);
    }
    catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e);}      
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать в конце writer.flush(), скорее всего остатки в буфере остались.

Answer (score 0):

В Java версии 1.7 появились новые классы для работы с файлами и синтаксис **try-with-resources**, которые облегчают жизнь и предотвращают подобные ошибки. Ваш код можно переписать следующим образом:

```
public void saveAsTxt(String path) {
    // собираем путь к файлу, с учетом системного разделителя 
    Path newFilePath = Paths.get( path,
            AuthorFirstName + " " + AuthorSecondName + " " + Title + ".txt" );
    // try-with-resources, после выхода из блока try потоки, 
    //   объявленные в заголовке будут автоматически закрыты
    // newBufferedWriter создаст новый файл, либо затрет существующий
    // Запись в файл будет вестись в текущей кодировке виртуальной машины
    try ( BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter( newFilePath, Charset.defaultCharset() ) ){
        processNodesToTxt();

        writer.write(TxtText);
        // writer и используемые им потоки будут закрыты после выхода из блока
        // специальный вызов writer.flush() не нужен
    }
    catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e);}      
}
```